# $A \subset C$ and $B \subset D$. Prove $A \times B \subset C \times D$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I understand that if all elements in A are contained in C and all elements in B are contained in D, then the Cartesian Product of C and D is a set that contains among its elements all the ordered pairs that can be formed with the elements of A and B. Therefore, $A \times B \subset C \times D$. This is an intuitive conclusion based on definitions and inspection. I would like a formal proof of this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: suppose $(a,b)\in A\times B$ so $a\in A\subset C$ and $b\in B\subset D$ thus $(a,b)\in C\times D$

Comment: why the downvote?! :/

Comment: this is the second time that i get punished with downvotes by a single mistake, and self evident in the body of the question, i don't get why people have to be so rude on questions.

Comment: @dacabdi Welcome to the club. Happens to me all the time on this site. I think it's because someone found the question too trivial and they think it's a dumb question. Sometimes people forget that what's easy for them may be hard for others. I try not to get offended. It's not like anyone knows who we really are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First,
$$A \subset C \Longleftrightarrow  \{x \in A \Longrightarrow x \in C\}$$
Similarly,
$$B \subset D \Longleftrightarrow  \{x \in B \Longrightarrow x \in D\}$$

We want to show that
$$A \times B \subset C \times D.$$

That is, we want to prove the implication
$$(y,z) \in A \times B \Longrightarrow (y,z) \in C \times D.$$

Suppose that
$$(y,z) \in A \times B.$$

This implies that
$$\{y \in A\} \land \{z \in B\}.$$

Consequently,
$$\{y \in C\} \land \{z \in D\}$$
is also true, since $A \subset C$ and $B \subset D$.

Finally,
$$(y, z) \in C \times D.$$

Since $y$ and $z$ were arbitrary, we have proved that
$$A \times B \subset C \times D.$$

Comment: this is the type of answer I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, @DavidCabrera!  =)

Answer (score 1):

The proof is very close to the intuition.

Let $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. This implies $a\in C$ and $b\in D$, which gives $(a,b)\in C\times D$.

It is true for any pair $(a,b)\in A\times B$, thus, $A\times B\subset C\times D$.

Answer (score 1):

Let a ∈ A. Then a ∈ C.

Let b ∈ B. Then b ∈ D.

Let (a,b) ∈ A×B.

Since A ⊆ C and B ⊆ D, a ∈ C and b ∈ D. Thus, (a,b) ∈ C×D.